# How to check if a js.Any value is a number in ScalaJS

Tags: scala.js

If you have a value of type js.Any is there an easy way to check to see if it's a number?

(this question was originally asked in the gitter room and is being record here)

Answer (score 4):

This question bring up 2 points.

1. js.Any should generally be avoided. Prefer instead to use scala.Any
2. In any case if you are stuck with a js.Any for some reason upcast it to a scala.Any then do a normal pattern match:

```
def isNumber(x : js.Any) : Boolean = {
  (x : Any) match {
     case x: Double => true
     case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: Humm... where is the check for number?